# iOS 8 Framework Distribution issue while uploading on app store

Tags: ios, frameworks, app-store, distribution

I have made on Framework for my own code so that no one can edit that code.

I have signed the framework properly and i have one app with that framework.

But when my client trying to upload their app with my framework and its code signing certificate and provisioning profile, App store submission fails.

Error :- invalid code signing. the executable must be signed with the certificate that is contained in provisioning profile.

My app is uploaded but my client's app not getting uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client need to sign with their own cert as the app is compiler and linked with your framework. Using your framework doesn't required your cert to sign unless you did something wrong when building the framework.

Comment: I have my client's certificate. I signed my framework with client's certificate and with my provisioning profile (wildcard app id no explicit id). But issue still exists with client. Wildcard app id has any issue with framework. should i change to explicit app id and create new provisioning profile ?

Comment: I don't need code sign to build the framework. I use this : [link](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) Not sure how you build the framework. May be you can try not to code sign as framework is not an app.

Comment: I will check the link you provided. But if i dont sign a my framework, then i will get compiler error that code signing is required for project type "Framework" in ios 8

Comment: i have create new framework from the link you provided. But when i add that framework in my app it crashes because i am passing my UIView and UIImage to that framework. so it is giving me unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

Comment: Kilogen9 thank you very much. Your link helps me a lot. My problem Got solved.

Comment: Good to hear that. Good luck.

Comment: Hey hi. One more thing to ask. If i am not signing my framework that means it is public and can be used by any one. ? i want to sign a framework and distribute to my client is this possible? or for distribution the framework i dont have to sign ?

Comment: as the framework is a static lib, you don't need to sign. anyone has the framework can use it. I never sign a framework before. May be you can try to sign with your client's cert and let me know the result as well. Thanks.